# Excel VBA move cells left or right based on value change (step)

Tags: vba, excel

Basically this is a list used for planning. The coloured bars are set manually based on a planning according to the columns Start date, End date.

This planning changes, so the coloured bars need to be adjusted manually to the right or to the left. I probably mislead you giving my ideas but could be of any use anyhow. I thought I make an extra column which calculates the difference in months (this is simple). If, for instance, we have this column with a number 6 and the planning moves to the left (re-scheduled) the number 6 would be reduced, so according to this reduction I would like to link the coloured bar to move automatically to the left (this is what I call a step) accordingly. If the deadline is extended, then move the coloured bar to the right.

I have already implemented a simple macro with a pop up calendar for picking up dates in a more professional way (sorry for my basic VBA skills), so the rest (the complicated part) is left. :)

p.s. I am really inexperienced and only managed to get the following, which moves cells to the right based on a change of number but no step, no 2 sided movement, really complicated and worried this is impossible.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Picture:

[image: PICTURE ATTACHED HERE]

Comment: you've got an interesting question but have also left dozens of questions unanswered. Perhaps you could address some of the questions left below and provide a description of at least one specific situation. I was wondering what you would do if a cell was blank and you typed a 9 into it.

Comment: Should work on all cells or in any particular cell/column/range?  Please let us know the expected result for at least 3 to 5 combinations of example.  Shifting refers to moving the current cells left or right or what?  Please make it more descriptive with examples.

Comment: thank you!!! I replied with an improved explanation, would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what my interpretation of the question allowed me to do:

```
Option Explicit

' Store the current state of your cell here!
'
' The value defaults to Zero on the first run.
' If you don't like that, you should call a
' function that stores the current value in
' here first...
Dim currentNum As Integer

Private Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if  the changed value belonged to
    ' your modifier-cell. If it didn't, exit
    ' the sub. Otherwise continue with your
    ' operation.
    If Not Target.Address = "A1" Then

        Exit Sub

    End If

    ' Use a for-loop to iterate over all the cells
    ' within a specific range.
    Dim c As Integer    ' Holds the current column
    Dim r As Integer    ' Holds the current row
                        '(inside the current column)

    ' Iterate over the columns...
    For c = 0 To <your_range>.Columns.Count

        ' Iterate over all rows in each column...
        For r = 0 To <your_range>.Rows.Count

            If Not IsEmpty(<your_range>.Cells(c,r)) Then

                ' I never know if c or r goes first.
                ' Make sure they're in the right order.

                ' Now, we're checking the current value
                ' of your cell against the nust updated new
                ' value:
                If GetModifierCellValue() > currentNum Then

                    ' The GetModifierCellValue()-Function doesn't exist. I recommend you write one.
                    ' Otherwise you could just query the value with the cell's address...

                    If c+(ABS(currentNum-GetModifierCellValue()) <= <your_range>.Columns.Count Then

                        ' Copy the value to the cell you'd like to shift to
                        <your_range>.Cells(c+(ABS(currentNum-GetModifierCellValue())), r).Value =_
                        <your_range>.Cells(c,r).Value
                        ' Again: maybe it has to be the other way round...

                        ' Empty the current cell
                        <your-range>.Cells(c,r).Value = ""

                    End If

                ElseIf GetModifierCellValue() < currentNum Then

                    If c-(ABS(currentNum-GetModifierCellValue()) >= 1 Then

                        ' Copy the value to the cell you'd like to shift to
                        <your_range>.Cells(c-(ABS(currentNum-GetModifierCellValue())), r).Value =_
                        <your_range>.Cells(c,r).Value
                        ' Again: maybe it has to be the other way round...

                        ' Empty the current cell
                        <your-range>.Cells(c,r).Value = ""

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

**Attention:** You should definitely read all of my comments. They're quite important. And since you are new to (VBA) programming, they might actually aid you well later in your coding career...

### Edit:

With the code above you are overwriting existing cells. If you'd like to avoid this, apply the changes (and only the changes!!) to a temporary table and then copy this temporary table to your real one.

**Also,** you can't use IsEmpty() for what you're trying to achieve. It doesn't take into account the background color of the cells (I believe...)! Use the cell's background color property instead.

Comment: having a certain rep for leaving comments is actually valuable, as it stops spamming and trolling from infecting the site.

Comment: That's true. But why can I leave comments to comments, then? Or can I only leave comments to my own Q/As ?

Comment: @anton86
I get what you're trying to do. Most of the code above would work for your intent as well. Just play around with it for a bit. There are properties for cell background colors, too. Use them instead of the 'Value' ones.

Comment: yes, you can only leave comments on your on Q/A's for now. That way you can communicate with people about what you are asking / providing help with.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are many unanswered questions in your question, even though it is an interesting question.

I have provided code below that will give you a great framework upon which to work. You'll need to make changes in the range references and maybe some of the logic, but I did piece it together from the little example you did provide, just to show how it would or could work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'will only fire if cell A1 is changed
'If Target.Column = 1 Then 'will only fire if any cell in column A is changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z10000")) Is Nothing Then 'will only fire if a cell in the A1:Z100000 is changed

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then 'further refine to make sure only one cell changed

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'first lets get the difference of the old value versus the new value
        Dim iOld As Integer, iNew As Integer, iSize As Integer 'using byte for the assumption that the numbers will always be small
        iNew = Target.Value2
        Application.Undo
        iOld = Target.Value2
        Target.Value = iNew 'reset change back after getting old value

        If iNew - iOld > 0 Then 'check to make sure difference is positive

            iSize = iNew - iOld

            Select Case iSize ' here you can set your conditions based on the difference

                Case Is > 1

                    Target.Resize(1, iSize).Insert shift:=xlToRight

                Case Is = 1

                    With Target

                        If .Column <> 1 Then  'because can't move anything to the left of column A
                            .Cut
                            .Offset(, -1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
                        End If

                    End With

            End Select

        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @anton86 - you **answered** with an explanation. please edit your original question with the explanation and delete the answer. furthermore, test this code out or tweak to fit your needs and then let me know what is or isn't working. This code is pretty comprehensive and will take you far.